# SVG colour distortions around text edges in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I'm using an inline SVG elemnt for text and in Firefox it renders with streaks of cyan and yellow around the text edges- which shouldn't be there.

Otherwise, it works well in Opera, Chromium and IE10.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<h1 style="background-color:black;">
<a href="/">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1">

  <defs>
    <linearGradient y2="100%" x2="0%" y1="0%" x1="0%" id="h_gradient">
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-opacity: 1; stop-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);"/>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-opacity: 1; stop-color: rgb(106, 106, 106);"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <filter id="innershadow" x0="-50%" y0="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset dy="3" dx="3"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" result="shadowDiff"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.6"/>
      <feComposite in2="shadowDiff" operator="in"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="over"/>
    </filter>

  </defs>

  <text font-family="inherit" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle"
    fill="url(#h_gradient)" filter="url(#innershadow)" x="50%" y="100">
    <tspan font-size="100" stroke="white">

      Example

    </tspan>
  </text>

</svg>
</a>
</h1>
```

I thought it happens only when filters or gradients are applied, but it happens even without them- they just make it more visible.

Can anyone tell why it happens?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have you added white color everywhere ? Where is yellow color applied in above code ?

Comment: There is no yellow colour— or any other colour for that matter— applied in my code and still it renders with those streaks around the text edges. I tried to emphasize the idea by setting everything to white

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sEjW5/ 
Does this help ?

Comment: Not really, the problem is still there for me- it's just not as visible with the red fill as it is with a gradient and shadow effects which I have in my graphic. [Here's a screenshot](http://imgur.com/g4XwEbl)

Comment: I updated the code to the full version, as it is in the screenshot.

Comment: Sounds similar to this... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471457

Comment: Thanks for the link, that does look similar. Does it mean that all filters are a no-go? Zooming in with ctrl + '+' beyond a certain point seems to render the problem unnoticeable: [i.imgur.com/GGlp4sB.png?1](http://i.imgur.com/GGlp4sB.png?1). Is there any way I could use this info to fix my graphic?